# Pivot Row on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a query that returns an entire row and I need to pivot this result into a new table.

```
SELECT id_no, stud_name, group_no, class_1, class_2, class_3, class_4 FROM tbl_stud_class
```

This returns the following:

```
| id_no | stud_name | group_no | class_1 | class_2 | class_3 | class 4 |
| 1     | John Doe  | A11      | 84      | 60      | 80      | 79      |
```

I need to be able to return this row as:

```
| id_no | stud_name | group_no | class   | grade |
| 1     | John Doe  | A11      | class_1 | 84    |
| 1     | John Doe  | A11      | class_2 | 60    |
| 1     | John Doe  | A11      | class_3 | 80    |
| 1     | John Doe  | A11      | class_4 | 79    |
```

Can someone point me to a way to do this please? 
I am very new to PostgreSQL so I have no idea where and how to start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [LATERAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html) in postgresql 9.3+

```
SELECT id_no, stud_name, group_no, class, grade
FROM   tbl_stud_class 
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( VALUES
                     ('class_1', class_1),
                     ('class_2', class_2),
                     ('class_3', class_3),
                     ('class_4', class_4)
            ) l(class, grade)
```

Answer (score 1):

Need this:

```
WITH tbl_stud_class
     (id_no, stud_name, group_no, class_1, class_2, class_3, class_4) AS
(
    VALUES
      (1, 'John Doe', 'All', 84, 60, 80, 79),
      (2, 'Aberel Dalton', 'Some', 75, 32, NULL, 80)
)

SELECT
    id_no, stud_name, group_no, 'class_1' AS class, class_1 AS grade
FROM
    tbl_stud_class
WHERE 
    class_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
    id_no, stud_name, group_no, 'class_2' AS class, class_2 AS grade 
FROM
    tbl_stud_class
WHERE 
    class_2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
    id_no, stud_name, group_no, 'class_3' AS class, class_3 AS grade
FROM
    tbl_stud_class
WHERE 
    class_3 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
    id_no, stud_name, group_no, 'class_4' AS class, class_4 AS grade
FROM
    tbl_stud_class 
WHERE 
    class_4 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY
    id_no, class ;
```

AFAIK, there is no way to do this in an automatic way. PostgreSQL has the [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) function, which does PIVOT, but it works the other way around (from your desired output to your input).

---

You have a shorter alternative, using [`arrays`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) and [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html):

```
WITH tbl_stud_class
     (id_no, stud_name, group_no, class_1, class_2, class_3, class_4) AS
(
    VALUES
      (1, 'John Doe', 'All', 84, 60, 80, 79),
      (2, 'Aberel Dalton', 'Some', 75, 32, NULL, 80)
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id_no, stud_name, group_no, 
        unnest(ARRAY['class_1', 'class_2', 'class_3', 'class_4']) AS class,
        unnest(ARRAY[ class_1,   class_2,   class_3,   class_4 ]) AS grade
    FROM
        tbl_stud_class
) AS s0        
WHERE
    grade is not null 
ORDER BY
    id_no, class ;
```

Comment: Works well too! Thanks so much!