# Postgres convert values to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have postgres table with structure:

```
|key| position |    date    |
|---|----------|------------|
| 1 |     5    | 2017-07-01 |
|---|----------|------------|
| 1 |     9    | 2017-07-02 |
|---|----------|------------|
| 2 |     4    | 2017-07-01 |
|---|----------|------------|
| 2 |     8    | 2017-07-02 |
```

But I need to have the selected data in a format like this:

```
| key | 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-02 |
|-----|------------|------------|
|  1  |      5     |      9     |
|-----|------------|------------|
|  2  |      4     |      8     |
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html please look here

Comment: Google pivot query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivot Row on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494299/pivot-row-on-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one row per key and per date, then one way is conditional aggregation

```
select 
key,
min(case when date = '2017-07-01' then position end) as "2017-07-01",
min(case when date = '2017-07-02' then position end) as "2017-07-02"
from t
group by key
```

Comment: thants, that's what I need