# How can I transpose table values in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

How can I transpose these values to take this table:

[image]

And make it look like this:

[image]

There's no Pivot function that I can use in postgresql and every time I try the crosstab function, I keep getting an error in my code. Let's pretend that my table is called select * from TAttributes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot Row on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494299/pivot-row-on-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres means `filter`:

```
select id,
       max(attributenumber) filter (where attributeid = 2000),
       max(attributenumber) filter (where attributeid = 2001),
       max(attributenumber) filter (where attributeid = 2002),
       max(attributenumber) filter (where attributeid = 2003)
from t
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3710e9c0016ef3d7366010467a4898ac) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: unfortunately, this just gives me null values throughout

Comment: @oaker . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The code works and answers your question.

Comment: Looks like it worked! Can I do the same with dates? for example, max(attributedate) filter (where attributeid = 2007), etc. I'm trying that out but it's giving me an ERROR: sytanx error at or near "max"

Comment: Yes, you can use dates.  `MAX()` works on pretty much all data types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,  
    MAX((SELECT attributenumber FROM public.t WHERE ext_t.id = id AND ext_t.attribuiteid = attribuiteid AND attribuiteid = 2000)) AS '2000',
    MAX((SELECT attributenumber FROM public.t WHERE ext_t.id = id AND ext_t.attribuiteid = attribuiteid AND attribuiteid = 2001)) AS '2001',
    MAX((SELECT attributenumber FROM public.t WHERE ext_t.id = id AND ext_t.attribuiteid = attribuiteid AND attribuiteid = 2002)) AS '2002',
    MAX((SELECT attributenumber FROM public.t WHERE ext_t.id = id AND ext_t.attribuiteid = attribuiteid AND attribuiteid = 2003)) AS '2003' 
FROM public.t ext_t GROUP BY id
```